# Code with multiple inheritance and too much public access

Tags: c++, inheritance, functional-programming, friend, template-meta-programming

I have the following chunk of code defining functor composition...

```
#pragma once
#include <tuple>

template<typename Args,std::size_t A,typename...F>
class _compose{};

template<typename...Args,std::size_t A,typename F,typename...G>
class _compose<std::tuple<Args...>,A,F,G...>
:private _compose<std::tuple<Args...>,A-1,G...>{
        const F f;
public:
   _compose(F _f,G...g):_compose<std::tuple<Args...>,A-1,G...>(g...),f(_f){};
    constexpr auto operator()(Args...args) const{
        return f(_compose<std::tuple<Args...>,A-1,G...>::operator()(args...));
    }
};

template<typename...Args,typename F>
class _compose<std::tuple<Args...>,1,F>{
    const F f;  
public:
    _compose(F _f):f(_f){};
    constexpr auto operator()(Args...args) const{
    return f(args...);
    }
};

template<typename...Args>
struct compose{
    template<typename...Fs>
    constexpr auto operator()(Fs...f){
        return _compose<std::tuple<Args...>,sizeof...(Fs),Fs...>(f...);
    }       
};
```

Using functor definitions such as:

```
template<typename T>
struct func1{
    constexpr auto operator()(T x){return x+1;}
};

template<int I,typename T>
class func2{
    const int i,j;
public:
    func2(int _j):i(I),j(_j){};
    constexpr auto operator()(T x){return x+i+j;}
};
```

I can compose `compose<int>()(func1<int>(),func2<1,int>(1))(1)` to return `4`.

Now for the question: is this a weak implementation?
1. I went the route of multiple inheritance where each `_compose<I>` inherits "downwards" from `_compose<I-1>` and so on until `_compose<1>`. This felt like an elegant solution but am not sure of the caveats. I know multiple inheritance is generally frowned upon.
2. I am unable to make the `_compose` constructor more hidden to the outside world. I tried to make the `compose` function a `friend` but none of my attempts compiled. Note that the `_compose<...>::operator()` is intended to be public as the `compose` function returns a `_compose` object.

Any suggestions to improve the above code is appreciated. Note that I compile under `g++ -std=c++1y`.

Thanks,

Comment: Multiple inheritance is when a class inherits from more than one base class - what you have is simply a (very long) chain of single inheritance (which might still be discouraged, but for different reasons than those for which multiple inheritance is discouraged).

Comment: Is the second template supposed to inherit from `compose` or `_compose`?

Comment: `compose` is just a proxy to easily construct a `_compose` object.  `_compose` is supposed to inherit from `_compose`. e.g. `_compose<3,..>` inherits from `_compose<2,...>`.

Comment: But in your code you inherit from `compose`, I'm getting an error that its name isn't found.

Comment: My mistake and edited accordingly...